# Pose Mode - Dynamic Updating of Mesh Attached to Armature

Tags: interface, rigging, armature

More of a visual annoyance I have on my hands,

When I grab a part of my armature, I can see the armature and bones dynamically move, but the position of the mesh connected to the armature won't follow until I click to release the armature part, where upon it will snap over to where it should be.

Typically when you drag a part of the armature, the mesh would update as you move, so I'm guessing its a toggle that I accidentally flipped, but I don't know where it would be or what it's called.

Would anyone happen to know?

Comment: In armature's panel , under display there is `delay refresh`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Many Thanks R00t

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Please do not add 'solved' into question titles.